# "Transpose" (rotate?) nested list

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list of lists of lists like this:

```
[
 [
  [a,b],
  [c,d]
 ],
 [
  [e,f],
  [g,h]
 ]
]
```

Basically, this is a cube of values.

What I want is a different order of items in the same cube, like this:

```
[
 [
  [a,e],
  [b,f]
 ],
 [
  [c,g],
  [d,h]
 ]
]
```

And, preferably, in a one-liner (yes, I do know that's not the best practice).

I know of the `map(list, *zip(a))` trick, but i couldn't figure out how to apply it here. Something with lambdas and maps, probably?

UPD: As for what I need it for --- I've done some tests for speeds of different sorting algorithms; each deepest list has values -- the times that the sorting algorithms that I tested took. These lists are in lists, which represent different types of tests, and the outer list has the same thing repeated for different test sizes. After such rotation, I will have list (test size) of lists (test type) of lists (sort type) of items (time), which is so much more convenient to plot.

Comment: What is the logic behind the rotation?

Comment: Basically, if you imagine those "squares" as horizontal layers of a cube (that is, they are in that order from top to bottom), then the result is a list of transposed vertical slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to first transpose all the sublists then transpose the newly transposed groups:

```
print([list(zip(*sub)) for sub in zip(*l)])
```

Output:

```
In [69]: [list(zip(*sub)) for sub in zip(*l)]
Out[69]: [[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f')], [('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]]
```

If you want some map foo with a lambda:

```
In [70]: list(map(list, map(lambda x: zip(*x), zip(*l))))
Out[70]: [[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f')], [('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h'
```

For python2 you don't need the extra map call but I would use `itertools.izip` to do the initial transpose.:

```
In [9]: from itertools import izip

In [10]: map(lambda x: zip(*x), izip(*l))
Out[10]: [[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f')], [('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]]
```